# iPhone app : MPMoviePlayer: PlayVideo in Landscape mode only

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have an iPhone app which runs in portrait mode only. But I want to make mpmovieplayer to play video in landscape mode only.

How can I achieve that?

Here is the code.

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:lblVideoName.text ofType:@"mp4" inDirectory:nil];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];
    NSLog(@"URL== %@",url);
    moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                    initWithContentURL:url];


    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: You don't need to do any settings in MPMovieController instead manage view orientation.

Answer (score 1):

You can present the movie in it's own view controller that's setup for landscape.

```
// in the VC where the user indicates he wants to see a movie...
- (void)startTheMovie {
    // run a storyboard segue with a modal transition, or ...
    MyMovieVC *movieVC = [[MyMovieVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyMovieVC" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:movieVC animated:YES];
}

// in MyMovieVC

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||
        (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

// and the code that you wrote on view will appear
```

You can include a dismiss button in this interface, or, the youtube way is to have it dismiss itself.  You can do that by subscribing to the finished notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
selector:@selector(moviePlayerFinished:)
name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
```

then, on the finished message

```
- (void)moviePlayerFinished:(NSNotification*)notification {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Note, if you're doing this in a tabbed interface, all the tabs - even the ones not visible - need to agree to let the interface turn landscape.  This makes some sense but has caused me heartache in the past.  I don't have a pretty solution to this.  My approach has been a publicly accessible BOOL isLandscapeOK on my AppDelegate.  This MovieVC would set it to YES, and the other tab VCs would answer portrait or landscape if isLandscapeOK==YES.

Comment: Referring to your final note: you could also simply display that viewController modally, hence without any of the described orientation-sideeffects (tab bar,navigation bar).